# Cucumber with Selenium Parameterizing using a simple txt file

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, gherkin

I have a doubt with Parameterization using text files. I know that is possible with Selenium, because I have done that, but I cannot do it with Cucumber.

I have red about that is possible using Json files, but I want to know if anybody here was able to do it with a simple txt file.

For example: doing something like this with Cucumber:

```
    @Parameterized.Parameter(value = 0)
    public String user;
    @Parameterized.Parameter(value = 1)
    public String pass;


    @Parameterized.Parameters
    public static Object[] data() {
        return SetDatax.getInstance().getData(StepDefinitionsTest.class);
    }
```

Best regards.

Comment: How are you planning to execute the tests? Becoz cucumber has its own runner which does not work well with most junit runner annotations. Also can u clarify the post with some more details

Comment: OK: I have a runner for cucumber, but my question is if it is possible to send parameters from a txt file (Retrieve the data from a text file) and send it to the respective fields.  I have red about that is possible with JSon file, and Excel.

Comment: U can mention the path to the specific txt file and acces the data in the first step of a scenario and store it in variables in the step definition class.

Comment: Thanks Grasshopper, but the idea was take the dato stored in the txt file, write it in the step definition class linke @Parameterized.Parameter(value = 0) public String user; I was doing that, the same than the example that I wrote, but it is sending the parameters to the fields in blank.